# The App does not show login page when signout

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

When the user clicks on the Logout button,the app should sign out and display the sign-in page.
When I click the Logout button,I can see this message on the console.
`Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.`. but the Sign in page is not showing.

Here are my codes..

sigout method

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
  }
```

logout button

```
ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            signOut();
                          },
                          child: const Text('Logout')),
```

MaterialApp Home

```
StreamBuilder(stream: auth.userChanges(), builder: (context,snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  return const HomePage();
                } else {
                  return const SignIn();
                }
              })
```

Explain why it does not work.